# extending html elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, extend

I am working on a tool that creates GUIs by assembling it from smaller pieces of the user's choice.
these smaller pieces are html elements that are created programaticly.

with efficiency in mind I wondered if these elements could share a prototype, just like plain javascript objects can.

this is my method for extending:

```
var extend = function(o){
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = o;
    var x = new F();
    x._proto_ = o;
    return x;
};
```

which is the same as Object.create(), it just keeps a reference to the prototype as in Mozilla.

so this works fine for plain objects:

```
var a = { x: 0, y: 1};
var b = extend(a);
b.y; // 1
```

but when I try to use it for actual html element it fails:

```
var a = document.createElement("div");
a.whatever = //whatever..
var b = extend(a);
document.body.appendChild(b); //this throws an error.
```

the error reads: "An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist."

what's the deal? is it not possible to do this with html elements?

any thoughts are appreciated..

Comment: Elements are native objects. They aren't pure JavaScript and modifying their prototype isn't always predictable. Why don't you create a jQuery-like element wrapper instead? That way, you leave the element intact and just extend your wrapper's prototype all you want.

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript-DOM_Prototypes_in_Mozilla

Comment: mplungjan - from what I understand from ur link, what I'm trying to do is unnessecery since all elements of the same html type allready share a prototype. does that sound right?

Comment: Blender - thats a good idea, I need to get a bit more into JQuery to understand what those 'wrappers' are.. do you happen to know of a good article about that?

Answer (score 1):

Because `b`, that you get after `extend` call, is not a DOM element, it's an object, that holds reference to DOM element in prototype.

P.S. Are you sure that you need `x.prototype = o;` line in `extend` function?

Comment: changed that to '_proto_' for clearity. it just holds a reference to the prototype so it can be accessed dynamically later on.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create, see the end of article
I think you don't need that line at all